# Custom entities created time is always the same

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom content entity type. When I create an instance, the first one got the right created time stamp. But starting with the second one, they all have the same created time stamp: as the first one have!

Why is this happening?

Base field definition:

```
$fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
  ->setLabel(t('Created'))
  ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'))
  ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Setter / getter methods:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCreatedTime() {
    return $this->get('created')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setCreatedTime($timestamp) {
    $this->set('created', $timestamp);
    return $this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my php code cached before adding the `setCreatedTime`method to my custom entity. After clearing the cache everything was fine!

So in general: add the `setCreatedTime` method to your custom entity to make your created timestamp work.